# Align 4 imagebutton horizontally

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm having probs trying to align 4 image buttons horizontally this layout. The buttons should be in the bottom above the admob unit.

I need some way to fix that keeping the previous layout elemets, if it's possible.

Thank you very much David

[image: No description]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CC000000"
    android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle" >


    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#CC000000"
        android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fondo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/fondo" >
        </ImageView>

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/calendar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar" >
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16sp" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dia"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="40sp" >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
           android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <!-- scrolling bottom pane -->

           <ScrollView
               android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"

               android:background="@drawable/scroll"
               android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:orientation="vertical" >

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/etResponse"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:textColor="#ffffff"
                       android:textSize="20sp" >
                   </TextView>
               </LinearLayout>
           </ScrollView>

           <ImageButton
               android:id="@+id/gp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
               android:background="@drawable/rounded"
               android:src="@drawable/gp" />

           <ImageButton
               android:id="@+id/wa"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/gp"
               android:background="@drawable/rounded"
               android:src="@drawable/wa" />

           <ImageButton
               android:id="@+id/fb"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tw"
               android:background="@drawable/rounded"
               android:src="@drawable/fb" />

           <ImageButton
               android:id="@+id/tw"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/wa"
               android:background="@drawable/rounded"
               android:src="@drawable/tw" />

       </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

  <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `LinearLayout` with the orientation `horizontal` arround the `ImageButtons`.